# REQUEST: Marching Soldiers

Tags: request, military, footsteps

Am in need of a platoon (or 2) of marching soldiers, with full gear, weapons, etc. Mostly need the sound of heavy combat boots on pavement/cobblestone/cement/what have you.

Any army or group of people from the 20th century would do (this is for WW2).

Thanks!

Comment: Im envisioning an imagineers type contraption...

Comment: Jay - dropped you an e-mail. Let me know.

Comment: The wooden box full of charcoal briquets trick might help augment what you wind up putting together.